# Which CSS code snippet is better for maintainability and perfomance

Tags: css

I have 2 code snippets.

Here is snippet 1:

```
#question-title-1 {
 cursor:pointer;
 color:blue;
 padding:10px;
}

#question-title-2 {
 cursor:pointer;
 color:red;
 padding:10px;
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
#question-title-1 , #question-title-2 {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:blue;
  padding:10px;
}

#question-title-2 {
  color:red;
}
```

Wich one is better and why?
I prefer 2 because it takes less lines of code. On the other hand i think redefining the color attribute will cause a repaint in the browser.

Comment: It wouldn't cause a repaint. Imagine how long it would take to render an HTML page if the browser painted the screen after parsing every line of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use 3 CSS declarations so you're not doing any overriding or duplicating properties:

```
#question-title-1,
#question-title-2 {
   cursor:pointer;
   padding:10px;
}

#question-title-1 { 
 color:blue; 
}

#question-title-2 {
 color:red;
}
```

It's more lines, but reducing lines shouldn't come head of structured CSS.

Answer (score 1):

To me better is second, maybe, but I believe the third option is the best:

```
#question-title{
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
}

#title-question{
  color:red;
}

#title-answer{
  color:red;
}
```

and then to use:

```
<div class="question-title title-question">
```

Comment: It's not ideal to use words like "red" & "blue" in css selectors. Use more semantic words e.g. ".title-alert", ".title-info" etc.

Comment: really? ouh, well of course. But here is not the question `which semantic` to use, but which `approach to use` when defining css classes. You could then comment on `question-title-1` as well, which would be very pointless for this question

Comment: True - It's just that I see this kind of thing in production code all the time and it's a little pet hate.

Comment: hehe :) It it is true :)) ok, I have modified it :) if some css beginners run into this code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the second. Rather not repeat same code. When there are changes that reflect both, you only have to change it once.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the best. This is because in terms of CSS, a DRY approach is always better, both for maintainability and performance. However, in this example (and in most cases when you're dealing with CSS) the performance gain is really insignificant, so you choose the option that is easiest to maintain.

Comment: I don't believe the second option is the best. Imagine you have a html/css code that you need to modify. Ok, you take a look at a title and see it uses `question-title-2` and you go to css and you run on first instance of question-title-2 and you see it is `blue`, then you all puzzled, look for second - and you see `red` and change it. And multiply that to multiple `class` definitions with multiple `css` and soon you will end up in very confusing css code where you wouldn't know how it is organized and you will get headache at a first taught at diving into `css` code.

Comment: Inheritance is a common pattern in CSS. In any dev tool (and quite possibly your IDE), you will get a decent overview of the property inheritance, so I believe this is a non-issue.

However, it might make more sense to create several rules, as Curt suggests in his answer. It depends on the use case. If ten selectors are sharing the property, but one does not, it might not make sense to split them.